# Rename filename to filename_inode (Unix)

Tags: unix

I would like to move my file from one location to another.

In the process, I want my filename to change from filename to filename_inode

Any idea how I can do that?

I know I can get the inode using

> ls -i $filename

I would prefer a solution that does not require me to download any addition features.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, you can do the following

1. `FILE=*<your-file-name>*`
2. `mv $FILE ${FILE}_$(ls -li $FILE | awk '{ print $1}')`